# how to invoke customview class methods into GLSurfaceview Class

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview, android-scroll

I want to add the `scrollTo()` and `scrollBy()` to `GLSurfaceview` class. This two methods are from the `View` class. Is it possible to invoke the above two methods on `GLSurfaceview` class?

Why? Because I want to scroll the `GLSurfaceview`. My Code is [HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/09f9q51xnqhq2l7/LineDraw_samplecode.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add these methods to GLSurfaceView class easily.

GLSurfaceView is actually a hole punching view. It has a transparent view to show the underneath surface that display the image. If you scroll this view, only transparent pixels are moved.

You should implement these features by using OpenGL ES1/2.